# ASP.NET Web API XmlFormatter SetSerializer

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, xmlserializer

I have configured a custom XmlSerializer for DateTime -

```
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.Indent = true;
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SetSerializer<DateTime>(new myDateTimeSerializer());
```

The custom myDateTimeSeriazlier  -

```
public class myDateTimeSerializer : System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer
    {
        public myDateTimeSerializer()
            : base()
        {
        }

        public override bool CanDeserialize(System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader)
        {
            return base.CanDeserialize(xmlReader);
        }
        protected override object Deserialize(System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader reader)
        {
            return base.Deserialize(reader);
        }
        protected override void Serialize(object o, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter writer)
        {
            base.Serialize(o, writer);
        }
    }
```

If i put break-points in all of the above methods in debug mode, it does not get hit.
Am i missing anything here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to replace the primitive type serialization. You have to use additional properties as string an format the string in the get. You can only register xmlserializer for your own object types.